# express constraint violation

Tags: logic, constraints

A very simple question, what's the mathematical symbol (expression) that represents constraint violation. Specifically, we have a set of constraints R each of which taking three variables, two sets of values S1 and S2 and we look for the constraints in R that some values in S1 and S2 does not violate, so how should I write the definition of such constraint(s)?

Comment: Why are the words "$C$ is unsatisfiable" not enough for you?

Comment: because we need an expression

Comment: x @user: What do you need an "expression" **for**? Your question is desperately missing motivation.

Comment: it's part of a formula we can not have half of the formula being text half of it being symbols

Comment: x @user: You need to give more context than that if you want a fighting chance of getting useful answers. Please edit the question to describe understandably what you're doing and which surroundings the symbol you're looking for would be placed in.